# scrapy-splash can't render this page - dynamic content not rendered?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen

I've recently decided to try Scrapy-Splash plugin, however it occurs that Splash cannot render this site http://orka.sejm.gov.pl/proc6.nsf/

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'

    start_urls = ['http://orka.sejm.gov.pl/proc6.nsf/']


    def start_requests(self):
            for url in self.start_urls:
                yield SplashRequest(url, callback=self.parse,
                    endpoint='render.html',
                    args={'wait': 20},)



    def parse(self, response):
        item = {}
        item["data"] = response.xpath('//html').extract()
        return item
```

So the result is something like this:

```
['<html><head>\n<title>Proces Legislacyjny 6 kadencja</title>\n<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">\n<!-- \nself._domino_name = "_Main";\n// -->\n</script>\n</head>\n\n<frameset frameborder="0" border="0" cols="169,1*">\n\n<frame frameborder="0" noresize name="Left" src="/proc6.nsf/start?OpenPage&amp;BaseTarget=Main">\n\n<frameset frameborder="0" rows="70,1*">\n\n<frame frameborder="0" noresize scrolling="no" name="Maintop" src="/proc6.nsf/pgHeader?OpenPage">\n\n<frame frameborder="0" noresize name="Main" src="/proc6.nsf/Przebieg%20procesu%20legislacyjnego%20-%20projekty%20ustaw?OpenView">\n</frameset>\n</frameset>\n\n</html>']
```

Clearly you can see that this isn't the same as when you visit the site with a regular browser. There's no table data and links and nice  tags.

Scrapy-Splash is missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splash correctly renders the page but you are using render.html which is return html of the main page and not frames inside it. You need to use render.json in this case with `iframes` set as 1.

See below issue for more details

https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/issues/413

**Edit-1**

I ran the below Lua script on the page and it gives me content of all the frames

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(5))

  local getFramesHtml = splash:jsfunc([[
   function test() { 
      var data = [];
      for (var i = 0 ; i < window.frames.length; i++)
       {
          data.push(window.frames[i].document.documentElement.outerHTML);
       }
      return data;
    }
    ]]);

  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    frames = getFramesHtml()
  }
end
```

[image: Splash Response]

Comment: well, it's still not the output similar to regular browser, look:
<p>{"geometry": [0, 0, 1024, 768], "url": "http://orka.sejm.gov.pl/proc6.nsf/", "title": "Proces Legislacyjny 6 kadencja", "requestedUrl": "http://orka.sejm.gov.pl/proc6.nsf/", "childFrames": [{"geometry": [0, 0, 169, 768], "url": "", "title": "", "requestedUrl": "http://orka.sejm.gov.pl/proc6.nsf/start?OpenPage&amp;BaseTarget=Main", "childFrames": [], "frameName": "Left"}, {"geometry": [169, 0, 855, 70], "url": "", "title": "", "requestedUrl": "http://orka.sejm.gov.pl/proc6.nsf/pgHeader?OpenPage", "childFrames": [], "frameN...

Comment: I mean, those ifames clearly are not loaded, is it because of CORS?

Comment: Or maybe rather - I've noticed that the page sends to itself a form. Will it render properly when I send a form via scrapy-splash? Is it even possible?

Comment: @MikolajM, please check my edit. You can call this function through scrapy and get the HTML

Comment: thanks :)  I see that you're using lua script to run some JS for each frame. what is this code for: data.push(window.frames[i].document.documentElement.outerHTML);
?

Comment: To get the HTML of each frame and create an array out of it